# setting layout params after animation

Tags: android, animation, layout

i have 2 views in a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_red"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_blue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now, i animate the y property of `view1` from 0 to 300. but i want `view2` to change its position according to `view1` - because `view2` is set to be below (layout-below) `view1`.

as this isn't working, i tried to add an `onAnimationEnd` listener to the animation. like this:

```
    ObjectAnimator ani = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1, "Y", 200);
    ani.setDuration(2000);
    ani.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, view2.getHeight());
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view1.getId());

            view2.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

but `view2` didn't change its position at all.

i would like to avoid making a new animation for `view2` if possible, so please don't bother to suggest one. ;)

does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Check this if it solves your problem:

```
ani.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            LayoutParams params = view2.getLayoutParams();
            // change it ...
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view1.getId());

            view2.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

Comment: sadly no. it didn't. still like before. view2 doesn't move from its initial place.